# What is MediaWiki's default EventStream endpoint?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

I'm setting up a MediaWiki based website locally. It's running with Apache on localhost. I'd like to set up some scripts to consume my wiki's event stream.

MediaTech has [docs](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Event_Platform/EventStreams) that show examples like this:

```py
import json
from sseclient import SSEClient as EventSource

url = 'https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange'
for event in EventSource(url):

    if event.event == 'message':

        try:

            change = json.loads(event.data)
        except ValueError:

            pass
        else:

            print('{user} edited {title}'.format(**change))
```

But I can't find any information on where the default stream endpoint is for a new install. I haven't set up any subdomains or anything, and all the examples I find use WMF streams.

What endpoint do I need to connect to in order to consume my wiki's event stream?

Thanks!

Comment: Your wiki does not have an event stream. EventStreams is a separate service, and fairly complex to set up.

Answer (score 1):

`'https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange'` streams all recent changes of all Wikimedia sites. To get recent changes of a single wiki you have to filter it by the returned content e.g. by the `'server_name'` key. As an alternative you may use Pywikibot's `eventstream` implementation:

```
import pywikibot
from pywikibot.eventstreams import site_rc_listener
site = pywikibot.Site('wikipedia:de')
for change in site_rc_listener(site, total=10):
    print('{type} on page {title} by {user}.'.format_map(change))
```